# App is crashing when i try to run it. Firebase authentication with MVVM and Navigation Component in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm, crash

I'm trying to build a simple app where the user enters his email address to sign up over Firebase with MVVM (Model View ViewModel).

when i try to observe the data in the view inside a fragment from the ViewModel the whole app crashes.

The error message says: **Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView**

**But when i remove the observing part from the View(The Login fragment the app runs correctlly)**

Can someone help me to fix that problem?

the App Repository

```
class AppRepo {

    private var application: Application? = null

    val userMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>? = null
    val loggedOutMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean>? = null
    val usernameMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>? = null
    val uriProfilePicMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<Uri>? = null


    private var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

    constructor(application: Application?) {
        this.application = application
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        if (firebaseAuth!!.currentUser != null) {

            val userID = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser)!!
                .uid

            userMutableLiveData!!.postValue(firebaseAuth!!.currentUser)


        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    fun loginUsers(email: String?, password: String?) {
        firebaseAuth!!.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email!!, password!!).addOnCompleteListener(
            application!!.mainExecutor,
            { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    userMutableLiveData!!.postValue(firebaseAuth!!.currentUser)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        application,
                        "Logging in failed: " + task.exception,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            })
    }

    @JvmName("getUserMutableLiveData1")
    fun getUserMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>? {
        return userMutableLiveData
    }
}
```

the ViewModel

```
open class ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var appRepo: AppRepo? = null
    private var userMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>? = null
    private var loggedOutMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean>? = null
    private var documentSnapshotMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<String>? = null
    private var uriProfilePocMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<Uri>? = null

    open fun ViewModel(application: Application) {

        appRepo = AppRepo(application)
        userMutableLiveData = appRepo!!.getUserMutableLiveData()
        loggedOutMutableLiveData = appRepo!!.getLoggedOutMutableLiveData()
        documentSnapshotMutableLiveData = appRepo!!.getUsernameMutableLiveData()
        uriProfilePocMutableLiveData = appRepo!!.getUriProfilePicMutableLiveData()
    }
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    open fun login(email: String?, password: String?) {
        appRepo!!.loginUsers(email, password)
    }

    open fun getUserMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser>? {
        return userMutableLiveData
    }

    open fun getUsernameMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<String>? {
        return documentSnapshotMutableLiveData
    }

    open fun getUriProfilePocMutableLiveData(): MutableLiveData<Uri>? {
        return uriProfilePocMutableLiveData
    }
}
```

the LoginFragment

```
abstract class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    private var emailEditText: EditText? = null
    private var passwordEditText:EditText? = null
    private var loginButton: Button? = null
    private var signupButton: Button? = null
    private var resetPasswordButton:Button? = null

    private var viewModel: ViewModel? = null


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
        emailEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.username)
        passwordEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.password)
        loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.login)

        loginButton!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val email = emailEditText!!.getText().toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
            val password = passwordEditText!!.getText().toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
            if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
                viewModel!!.login(email, password)
            }
        })

        return view

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)
        activity?.let {
            viewModel!!.getUserMutableLiveData()!!.observe(
                it,
                { firebaseUser ->
                    if (firebaseUser != null) {
                        Navigation.findNavController(requireView())
                            .navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment3_to_mainUIFragment)
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

XML File MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="false"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="17dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="221dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The issue is with the navigation component . Make sure you have added required fragments in the navgraph

Comment: I've already added the fragments and the actions yo the navgraph

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: If you update `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` to `class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` it might be fixed. Try that. I do recommend that you paste your error logs in questions so that we can help better.